# Webservice Integration

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-2010

I have to integrate with a third-party webservice, they send us an example in VB.NET. I have no idea how could I do the same in Delphi. I have the values of "URL_WS", "CERTIFICADO_WS" and "CONFIG_STRING"

VB.NET exemple:

```
Dim ServiceEndpoint = New EndpointAddress(New Uri(URL_WS),
EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(CERTIFICADO_WS)
Dim Binding = New WSHttpBinding()
Binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message
Binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName
Dim result = New Integracao.IintegracaoClient(Binding, ServiceEndpoint)
result.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None
result.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = CONFIG_STRING
result.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ""
```

Comment: Which part of the conversion are you having trouble with?

Comment: Actually, all of it. I never worked with web services that require some kind of authentication. I imported the wsld using "WSDL Importer" and have no idea the steps to replicate that "authentication" in Delphi.

Comment: Then start working through it step by step. Stack Overflow isn't a code-translation service.